# Column takes whole screen space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I am working on a simple POC that displays a form and takes some input from the user, so far it looks like this:

[image]

The layout is declared as follow:

```
Column {
   Row {
      TextInput {} Space() TextInput{}
   }
   Row {
      TextInput {} Space() TextInput{}
   }
}
```

So far so good. Now I would like to take it one step further and add input validation, eg.: if the input is invalid then show a `Text()` with red color underneath the `TextInput`. To do this I am wrapping the individual `TextInput`s in a `Column`, like this:

```
Column {
   Row {
      Column {
        TextInput {}
        Text(text="invalid input")
      } 
      Space() 
      Column {
        TextInput{}
        Text(text="invalid input")
      }
   }
   // ...
```

However, as you can see from the screenshot below, the column takes the whole height of the screen, which is not what I would expect:

[image]

Any ideas what am I missing?

**The actual code**:

```
@Composable
fun FormView(
    buttonEnabled: Boolean,
    onInterestChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onPrincipalChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onLoanChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onYearsChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onCalculateButtonClicked: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row {
        Column {
            InputField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                label = "Interest %",
                onValueChanged = { interest ->
                    onInterestChanged(interest)
                }
            )
            Text(text = "Invalid number", color = Color.Red)
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Column {
            InputField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                label = "Principal %",
                onValueChanged = { principal ->
                    onPrincipalChanged(principal)
                }
            )
            Text(text = "Invalid number", color = Color.Red)
        }

    }

   // second row ...
}

@Composable
fun InputField(modifier: Modifier, label: String, onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    var value: String by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        value = value,
        maxLines = 1,
        onValueChange = {
            value = it
            onValueChanged(value)
        },
        label = { Text(text = label) }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was because of the `Modifier.weight(1)` which was passed down to the `TextInput`. Adding a `Column` would apply the weight vertically as well.

```
@Composable
fun FormView(
    // ...
) {
    Row {
        Column {
            InputField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                ...
            )
         }
        ...
     }
}

@Composable
fun InputField(modifier: Modifier, ...) {
   
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        // ...
    )
}
```

To fix it, the modifier has to be applied to the `Column`:

```
// ... 
Row {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        InputField()
    }
}
```